# Constraint on function type using data kind

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming, data-kinds, kotlin-sealed

I'm confused about data kinds. Suppose we have

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
...
data Format
  = Photo
      { bytes :: Int
      }
  | Video
      { bytes       :: Int
      , durationSec :: Int
      }
```

I want to make then function with promouted type:

```
createVideo :: Int -> Int -> 'Video
createVideo _ _ = error "Not implemented"
```

Compiller this will ask us for parameters, and with them it give msg 'Video Int Int has kind `Format'.
i would like this compile-time behavior similar to kotlin:

```
sealed class Format {

  abstract val bytes: Int
  data class Photo(override val bytes: Int) : Format()
  data class Video(override val bytes: Int, val durationSec: Int) : Format()
}

private fun createVideo(bytes: Int, durationSec: Int) : Format.Video {
  return Format.Video(bytes, durationSec)
}

fun main() {
  val video: Format = createVideo(bytes = 0, durationSec = 0) // correct
  val video2: Format.Video = createVideo(bytes = 0, durationSec = 0) // correct
  val video3: Format.Photo = createVideo(bytes = 0, durationSec = 0) // compiler error 
}
```

In repl https://pl.kotl.in/2G9E1Cbgs

Comment: Is your question about DataKinds or about translating your example Kotlin program to Haskell? I'm asking because I don't think there is a direct connection between the two. I think DataKinds simply isn't the right way to write the equivalent of that Kotlin code (or at least you need more than just DataKinds).

Comment: Just similar behavior. Kotlin is just an example(probably it was better not to bring this piece of code, it confuses, sorry). I understand that in Haskell there is a completely different mechanism for this. I thought that this can be achieved with DataKinds only, but apparently not.

Comment: You can do this with `DataKinds`, but this seems more complicated than necessary unless you require it for reason which you have not mentioned. Do you have a particular reason for tracking which constructor is being used at a type-level? If not, I would suggest against it, since it makes the code more complicated and makes the types more difficult to work with. Sometimes this *is* necessary for something. But if it isn't, why go for the extra difficulty?

Comment: Ah, I see the compiler error part of your question. Why not make `Video` and `Photo` separate types? You could use a type class method to extract the bytes from values of both types (and perhaps have a smart constructor that works for both), if you need to have that ability.

Comment: There is no definite practical task, the question is purely theoretical. This is one of the perverted ways to study the type system, "or you can do it this way, but you can do it differently" :) K. A. Buhr gave great answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Data kinds do not provide a direct mechanism to check the value of a data structure at compile time.  In other words, if you have a data type:

```
data Format
  = Photo
      { bytes :: Int
      }
  | Video
      { bytes       :: Int
      , durationSec :: Int
      }
```

that is suitable for representing photos and videos, using the `DataKinds` extension to promote it to the type level does *not* allow you to write functions that accept only 10-second videos:

```
processTenSecondVideo :: Video bytes 10 -> IO ()    -- does not work
```

or even generate a `Format` value that is guaranteed to be a video:

```
createVideo1 :: Int -> Int -> Format                 -- works
createVideo2 :: Int -> Int -> Video bytes duration   -- does not work
```

From a technical standpoint, the new types `Photo` and `Video` that are promoted by the `DataKinds` extension are types of a kind (specifically, the new kind `Format`) that does not support values.  So, while values of type `Int` exist (because `Int` is of kind `*`, the kind of types that have values), no values of type `Photo 0` or `Video 128000 10` exist.  So, you can't use these types as return types (or argument types) of functions.

So, what use are data kinds?  Well, if you have a data structure that you want to somehow constrain at compile time, you don't promote *that* data structure.  Instead you promote other data structures to use as tools to write a type-level program to constrain the target data structure.

In your example, the constraints you want to put on your data structure are really quite modest:  you want to check if the data structure is or isn't a `Video`.  You don't need data kinds to do this.  Regular Haskell types are adequate if you just rearrange your data structure a bit.  Separating the formats into two types:

```
data Photo = Photo {bytes :: Int}
data Video = Video {bytes :: Int, durationSec :: Int}
```

is enough to distinguish videos from non-videos at compile time.  If you have parts of your program where you want to work with a value that can be either a video or a photo, you can introduce a sum type:

```
data Format = PhotoF Photo | VideoF Video
```

Data kinds become useful when the constraints become more complicated.  For example, suppose you wanted to censor photos videos to make them safe for the whole family:

```
censorPhoto :: Photo -> Photo
censorVideo :: Video -> Video
```

and allow users to generate screenshots:

```
screenShot :: Video -> Photo
```

You might like, at compile time, to ensure you don't accidentally censor a video twice, or show an uncensored video to a younger audience, or let someone bypass your censoring by taking screenshots of uncensored videos and passing them off as censored photos.

You could accomplish this by introducing more types:

```
data UncensoredPhoto = UncensoredPhoto {bytes :: Int}
data UncensoredVideo = UncensoredVideo {bytes :: Int, durationSec :: Int}
data UncensoredFormat = UncensoredPhotoF UncensoredPhoto | UncensoredVideoF UncensoredVideo
data CensoredPhoto = CensoredPhoto {bytes :: Int}
data CensoredVideo = CensoredVideo {bytes :: Int, durationSec :: Int}
data CensoredFormat = CensoredPhotoF CensoredPhoto | CensoredVideoF CensoredVideo
data AnyPhoto = UncensoredPhotoA UncensoredPhoto | CensoredPhotoA CensoredPhoto
data AnyVideo = UncensoredVideoA UncensoredVideo | CensoredVideoA CensoredVideo
data AnyFormat = AnyPhotoF AnyPhoto | AnyVideoF AnyVideo
```

so you can write things like:

```
censorFormat :: UncensoredFormat -> CensoredFormat
censoredScreenshot :: CensoredVideo -> CensoredPhoto
uncensoredScreenshot :: UncensoredVideo -> UncensoredPhoto
showAdult :: AnyFormat -> IO ()
showChild :: CensoredFormat -> IO ()
```

That's pretty messy, though.  And suppose you want to add some constraints on video length to prevent spammers from submitting lots of short videos, or to avoid tying up your servers censoring really long videos.  How many types along the line of `ShortUncensoredVideo` do you want to define?

In a situation like this, you can use data kinds to develop a type-level "language" for describing attributes of your data structures:

```
 {-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
 {-# LANGUAGE DuplicateRecordFields #-}
 {-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
 {-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
 {-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

-- these types/constructors will be promoted...
data Censoring = Censored | Uncensored
data Length = Short | Medium | Long

-- ...and used to tag our actual data structures
data Photo (c :: Censoring) = Photo { bytes :: Int }
data Video (c :: Censoring) (l :: Length) = Video {bytes :: Int, durationSec :: Int}
data Format (c :: Censoring) where
  PhotoF :: Photo c -> Format c
  VideoF :: Video c l -> Format c
```

Now we can write things like:

```
-- preserve censoring at compile time
screenShot :: Video c l -> Photo c
screenShot (Video b _) = Photo (b `div` 10)

-- only censor uncensored videos that aren't long
type family NotLong l where
    NotLong Long = False
    NotLong l = True
censorVideo :: (NotLong l ~ True) => Video Uncensored l -> Video Censored l
censorVideo (Video b l) = Video (b `div` 2) (l `div` 2)

-- show any format to adults
showAdult :: Format c -> IO ()
showAdult fmt = print fmt

-- only censored content for kids
showChild :: Format Censored -> IO ()
showChild fmt = print fmt
```

and catch problems at compile time:

```
main = do
  -- we can show a screenshot from a censored version of an uncensored short video to a child
  showChild $ PhotoF . screenShot . censorVideo $ (Video 128000 1 :: Video 'Uncensored 'Short)

  -- but the following are compilation errors
  --   can't censor an already censored video
  showAdult $ VideoF . censorVideo $ (Video 128000 1 :: Video 'Censored 'Short)
  --   can't censor a long video
  showAdult $ VideoF . censorVideo $ (Video 12800000 100 :: Video 'Uncensored 'Long)
  --   can't show a child an uncensored screenshot
  showChild $ PhotoF . screenShot $ (Video 128000 1 :: Video 'Uncensored 'Short)
```

Note that the promoted types (`Censored`, `Uncensored`, `Short`, `Medium`, `Long`) and kinds (`Censoring` and `Length`) are not directly related to the unpromoted types `Photo`, `Video`, and `Format` that they describe.  As I say, this is how data kinds are typically used.

Full code example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DuplicateRecordFields #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

-- these types/constructors will be promoted...
data Censoring = Censored | Uncensored
data Length = Short | Medium | Long

-- ...and used to tag our actual data structures
data Photo (c :: Censoring) = Photo { bytes :: Int }
data Video (c :: Censoring) (l :: Length) = Video {bytes :: Int, durationSec :: Int}
data Format (c :: Censoring) where
  PhotoF :: Photo c -> Format c
  VideoF :: Video c l -> Format c
instance Show (Format c) where show _ = "<Format>"

-- preserve censoring at compile time
screenShot :: Video c l -> Photo c
screenShot (Video b _) = Photo (b `div` 10)

-- only censor uncensored videos that aren't long
type family NotLong l where
    NotLong Long = False
    NotLong l = True
censorVideo :: (NotLong l ~ True) => Video Uncensored l -> Video Censored l
censorVideo (Video b l) = Video (b `div` 2) (l `div` 2)

-- show any format to adults
showAdult :: Format c -> IO ()
showAdult fmt = print fmt

-- only censored content for kids
showChild :: Format Censored -> IO ()
showChild fmt = print fmt

main = do
  -- we can show a screenshot from a censored version of an uncensored short video to a child
  showChild $ PhotoF . screenShot . censorVideo $ (Video 128000 1 :: Video 'Uncensored 'Short)

  -- but the following are compilation errors
  --   can't censor an already censored video
  showAdult $ VideoF . censorVideo $ (Video 128000 1 :: Video 'Censored 'Short)
  --   can't censor a long video
  showAdult $ VideoF . censorVideo $ (Video 12800000 100 :: Video 'Uncensored 'Long)
  --   can't show a child an uncensored screenshot
  showChild $ PhotoF . screenShot $ (Video 128000 1 :: Video 'Uncensored 'Short)
```